# How to open two separate consoles and write different data onto them?

Tags: c++, windows-7, console, interpreter, brainfuck

I made a brainfuck interpreter in c++ and launched a very slow program. I want to have two consoles: one with the input/output and one for debugging wich will show the variables, the instruction I am currently running etc. so that I can see if the program is stuck or something.

Thanks for the support!

Comment: I believe you can do it by creating another process and passing your output handle to it but it won't be that easy because it's not documented that well. You can find some info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx) but actually example provided is pretty buggy if I remember correctly. Maybe writing GUI application which simulates two consoles will be easier option?

Comment: A process can create only one console.  If you need two then you *must* create two separate processes.  The effort required in getting these processes to co-operate isn't worth it, CreateWindowEx() lets you create any number of windows.

Comment: Suggestion: Write output to both file and stdout. Write error to stderr. Open file in editor that can refresh a file (Notepad++, for example).

Answer (score 0):

When I work with ncurses on Linux:

I manually open a terminal in the conventional way, and in the terminal

- issue the command "tty" to find out the device name, and
- issue a "cd" to set the focus to the working dir.

> ```
> dmoen@C5:~$ tty
> /dev/pts/5
> dmoen@C5:~$ cd work
> dmoen@C5:~/work$
> ```

Then I start my program (in a different tty, or more often inside of gdb inside of emacs), and let the program I am working on know which device I want it to use for this special / debug output in the most convenient way.  Early in development, I might hard-code "/dev/pts/5" into the app under development, but I usually pass the "/dev/pts/1" info on the command line.

Comment: Missed the [windows-7] tag on the question?

Comment: doesn't matter, I'll make a linux version too.

Comment: Yes .. sorry.  Missed the windows tag